# Why is the compositionComplete event not called in durandaljs

Tags: javascript, durandal

Thats my sample project (8,3 MB) Visual Studio 2012 solution:

[sample project zipped](http://www.sendspace.com/file/dnp4n5)

My problem:

module **step2** and its compositionComplete event is NOT called!
module **step1** is and the same event works fine!

This way you can reproduce the problem:

1.) start app

2.) click the 'Browse schoolyears' button

3.) click the 'create' button (open the SchoolyearWizard)

4.) Wizard step1 is visible and its compositionComplete event is called

5.) click the 'next' button

6.) Wizard step2 is visible and its compositionComplete event is NOT called

I am posting here the important stuff only and these are 5 modules.

- The SchoolyearDialog module is composed of the SchoolyearBrowser and SchoolyearWizard module. Both modules are switched with the 'compose: activeScreen' binding.
- When the SchoolyearWizard is loaded and the user clicked the next step button to load step2 then here is the problem see number 6.) above.

**SchoolyearDialog**

```
define(['durandal/app','plugins/dialog', 'knockout', 'services/dataservice', 'plugins/router', 'moment'], function (app, dialog, ko, dataservice, router, moment) {

    var SchoolyearDialog = function () {

        var self = this;
        self.activeScreen = ko.observable('viewmodels/SchoolyearBrowser'); // set the schoolyear browser as default module 

        app.on('activateStep1').then(function (obj) {
            self.activeScreen(obj.moduleId);
        });

        app.on('activateStep2').then(function (obj) {          
            self.activeScreen(obj.moduleId);
        });

        app.on('dialog:close').then(function (options) {

            dialog.close(self, options );
        });

        self.closeDialog = function () {            
            dialog.close(self, { isSuccess: false });
        }
    }

    SchoolyearDialog.show = function () {

        return dialog.show(new SchoolyearDialog());
    };   

    return SchoolyearDialog;
});
```

**SchoolyearBrowser**

```
define(['durandal/app', 'plugins/dialog', 'knockout', 'services/dataservice', 'plugins/router', 'moment'],
    function (app, dialog, ko, dataservice, router, moment) {
        var SchoolyearBrowser = function () {
            var self = this;

            self.create = function () {
                app.trigger('activateStep1', {
                    moduleId: 'viewmodels/SchoolyearWizard',
                    viewMode: 'create'
                });
            }

            self.open = function () {
                // do not open the wizard
            }

            self.compositionComplete = function (view) {
                debugger;
            }
        };
        return SchoolyearBrowser;
    });
```

**SchoolyearWizard**

```
define(['durandal/activator', 'viewmodels/step1', 'viewmodels/step2', 'knockout', 'plugins/dialog','durandal/app'], function (activator, Step1, Step2, ko, dialog, app) {

    var steps = [new Step1(), new Step2()];
    var step = ko.observable(0);   // Start with first step

    var activeStep = activator.create();

    var stepsLength = steps.length;

    var hasPrevious = ko.computed(function () {
        return step() > 0;
    });

    var caption = ko.computed(function () {

        if (step() === stepsLength - 1) {            
            return 'save';
        }
        else if (step() < stepsLength) {
            return 'next';
        }
    });

    activeStep(steps[step()]);

    var hasNext = ko.computed(function () {
        if ((step() === stepsLength - 1) && activeStep().isValid()) {
            // save
            return true;
        } else if ((step() < stepsLength - 1) && activeStep().isValid()) {

            return true;
        }
    });

    return {
        showCodeUrl: true,
        steps: steps,
        step: step,
        activeStep: activeStep,
        next: next,
        caption: caption,
        previous: previous,
        hasPrevious: hasPrevious,
        hasNext: hasNext
    };

    function isLastStep() {
        return step() === stepsLength - 1;
    }

    function next() {

        if (isLastStep()) {

            // Corrects the button caption when the user re-visits the wizard
            step(step() - 1);
            // Resets the wizard init page to the first step when the user re-visits the wizard
            activeStep(steps[0]); 
            debugger;
            // save;

        }
        else if (step() < stepsLength) {
            step(step() + 1);
            activeStep(steps[step()]);
            debugger;
            //app.trigger('activateStep2', {
            //    moduleId: 'viewmodels/step2'
            //});
        }
    }

    function previous() {
        if (step() > 0) {
            step(step() - 1);
            activeStep(steps[step()]);
        }
    }
});
```

**Step1**

```
define(function () {
    return function () {
        var self = this;

        self.isValid = function () {
            return true;
        }
        self.name = 'step1';

        self.compositionComplete = function (view) {
            debugger;            
        }
    };
});
```

**Step2**

```
define(function () {
    return function () {

        this.isValid = function () {
            return true;
        }
        this.name = 'step2';

        self.compositionComplete = function (view) {

           // I never get here WHY ???            
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your step 2 you don't have a self.compositionCompleted event because you don't have a context 'self'

You need to declare self = this;

```
var self =this;
self.name = whatever;
self.compositionComplete
```

Comment: ahahah and in step1 I did it :P stupido. Thanks for your eyes!